# Do we lose everything, if the natural transformations in a monad are exactly inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, transformation, type-theory

I'm currently explaining monads

$$T:{\bf C}\to{\bf C},\hspace{1cm}\eta:1_{\bf C}\to T,\hspace{1cm}\mu:T\circ T\to T,$$

to my brain and the "only" tricky thing are really the [identity relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28category_theory%29#Formal_definition).

I came up with a potential argument why this definition is the natural thing to define, in particularly over easier candidates.

Is the following right?

> In the case where, for all $A\in\mathrm{Ob}_{\bf C}$, we have
>
> (edit)
>
> $$\eta_{TA}\circ\mu_{A}=id_{TTA},$$
>
> the monad constrcution (for programming purposes say) is useless because it actually just shifts all of the (type) structure, i.e. merely renaming all participants. The fact that $\mu$ is generally not the direct invers of $\eta$ allows there for something to be added or lost.

Comment: The equality $\mu_{TA}\circ\eta_{A}=id_A$ has no sense: it is not well typed.

Comment: @user21929: Okay, so does $\mu_{TTA}\circ\eta_{TA}=id_{TA}$ do it? The component of $\eta$ at $TA$ mapps to $TTA$ and the component of $\mu$ at $TTA$ should map back to $TA$ --- Remark: In any case, I should also emphasize that I want to speak of a bijection here (so that the (suitably well typed) reverse order of concatenations of the natural transform is the identity too.)

Comment: No, $\mu_{TTA} \circ \eta_{TA} = id_{TA}$ has no sense: the component of $\mu$ at $TTA$ goes from $TTTTA$ to $TTTA$. The equality $\mu_A \circ \eta_{TA} = id_{TA}$, instead, does always hold for any monad.

Comment: @user21929: Ah, okay I see, the index of $\mu$ doesn't coincide with it's domain then. I've updated the questions, hopefully well typed, with the reverse concatenation which should be non-trivial in general. /// As an example I think of $\text{return}(x):=[x]$ and flatten as join (e.g. $\text{join}([[a,b,c],[e],[f,g]]):=[a,b,c,e,f,g]$), which -coming from the list of lists side- can't be inverse to each other. So then if a monad were defined to require the natural morphism components to be strict inverses, would the monad be merely a relabeling or could there still be nontrivial applications?

Comment: @NiftyKitty95 $\eta_{TA} \circ \mu_A$ while being well typed is usually false for monads. Consider $T$ the free monoid monad then for every set $X$ we have $T(X)$ the free-monoid. Now $\mu_X((x),(y))=(x,y)$ where $x,y \in X$ and $\eta_{TX}\circ \mu_X ((x),(y))=((x,y)) \ne ((x),(y))$ to $\eta_{TX} \circ \mu_X \ne 1_{TTX}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: Thanks for the example. I guess the question doesn't imply that the relation is generally true - I ask if we require the natural transfomrations (which are a family of endomorphisms) are exact inverses/bijections $\eta=\mu^{-1}$, if then the image of $1_{\bf C}$ (the category itself) and the image of $T$ can be distinguished in any way, apart from objects and arrows having different names. If $\eta=\mu^{-1}$, can $T$ add or remove anything to the objects which wasn't there before (like the Maybe monad in Haskell adds a new value to every type.)

Answer (score 2):

In the case $\mu$ is a natural isomorphism, the monad is said to be *idempotent*. In this case, the forgetful functor from the Eilenberg-Moore category of algebras is full and faithful.